# Hide a single guide in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, guides, snapping

I have several guides in Inkscape that converge in a certain area, making snapping to the one I want difficult. Is there a way to just hide certain guides but leave others visible?

I know you can "hide all guides" but I still need a couple of them to be visible for snapping to.

Comment: I zoom in a lot, draw a rect, hide guides, draw actual shape snapped to corner of rect, delete rect, show guides

Comment: No there isn't. However you could draw a normal line snapped to your existing guide, hide the guides, and use that line for snapping, then delete it afterwards.

Comment: If you can get rid of the offensive guides, you can also drag them to the ruler and they will dissapear. NOTICE once done they wont come back.